# How do I find the closest number in a list that is greater than my number?

Tags: python, list

I want to get the closest number (or the index of it) in a list that is greater than a given number.
The list:

```
lst=[1,2,5]
```

My number:

```
num=3
```

If I use: `min(lst, key=lambda x:abs(x-num))`
it will give `2` but I want it to give me `5`

Comment: Is the list always already sorted?

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider numbers greater than `num`:

```
output, index = min((i, idx) for idx, i in enumerate(lst) if i>num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write an actual loop to do it:

```
closest_greater = None
for item in lst:
    if item > num and (closest_greater is None or item < closest_greater):
        closest_greater = item
```

gives `closest_greater = 5`

Alternatively, you could give the `min()` function a generator expression that includes only elements that are greater than `num`

```
min(i for i in lst if i > num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to use a binary sort? In my tests, this is slightly faster.

```
import time
from bisect import bisect


def timer(func):
    def function_timer(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print "The runtime took {} seconds to complete".format(round(time.time() - start, 2))

    return function_timer


test_list = [1, 7, 5, 6, 3, 8]
k = 3

@timer
def t1():
    for x in range(1000000):
        test_list[bisect(test_list, k)]


@timer
def t2():
    for x in range(1000000):
        min((i, idx) for idx, i in enumerate(test_list) if i > k)
```

yields

```
The runtime took 0.22 seconds to complete
The runtime took 0.94 seconds to complete
```